# Image URL is passed from one activity to another but it's not assigned to the variable

Tags: android, android-intent

I have retrieved image URL from firebase database and it is passed to next activity. The next activity has received it but its not assigned to the variable. It's Null.

Here is the code that I have used:

Activity.java

```
String url=user.imageURL;

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("image", url);
Intent in=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DisplayAcc.class);
in.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(in);
```

Display.java

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String key = bundle.getString("image");
URL.setText(key);
Picasso.with(this).load(key).placeholder(R.drawable.camera).error(R.drawable.arrow).fit().into(IMAGE, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

    }
});
```

when debugged Diaplay.java, I got this in debugger console:

```
bundle=Bundle[{_fbSourceApplicationHasBeenSet=true, image=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/database-6c62b.appspot.com/o/Accident%2FAccident907.jpg?alt=media&token=dfd78176-9f57-4e55-afca-da5e352d5507}]
key=null
URL=null
```

Because of this i get an error saying

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null" for picasso
>
> OR
>
> "Attempt to invoke virtual method void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference" for TextView(URL).

Please help me out.

Comment: The `setText` error sounds like it's trying to say that the `URL` variable is null, not the `key` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're forgetting to bind the view with `ButterKnife` from your previous code:

```
public class DisplayAcc extends AppCompatActivity {

  @BindView(R.id.image) ImageView IMAGE;
  @BindView(R.id.url) TextView URL;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_acc);

    // You forgot this
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: i had forgotten the most important part.

Comment: @LavanyaManoj: You're very welcome ;). If this answer solve your problem, please mark it as an Accepted Answer.

Comment: well my reputation is 8 and i need 15 to upvote :(((

Answer (score 2):

Do ensure you are not passing null url from `Activity.java`

Or try this

to pass from `Activity.java`

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity.this, 
Display.class);
myIntent.putExtra("image", url);   
startActivity(myIntent);
```

to retreive from Display.java

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
String url = myIntent.getStringExtra("image");
```

Comment: did you checked the url value in Activity.java